# skimage feature module missing documented attributes

Tags: python, scikit-image

I'm running one of the examples from `skimage` [documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_trainable_segmentation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-segmentation-plot-trainable-segmentation-py) and struggling to find either the `multiscale_basic_features` referenced there as an attribute of the `skimage.feature` module or its current equivalent. Does anyone know what I can substitute it with in the following segment of their code?:

```
features_func = partial(feature.multiscale_basic_features, intensity=True, edges=False, texture=True,
                    sigma_min=sigma_min, sigma_max=sigma_max,
                    multichannel=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to upgrade your scikit-image version. That function was only added in 0.18.1.